# MYSQL Query Passed variable result 0

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, networking

I've been trying to run a VERY simple MySQL query to no avail. I've scoured forums, tried multiple things, and this will not work for the life of me.

Im hoping someone can point out the error as its probably something REALLY stupid or REALLY Simple.

I have a nodejs application that has an async promise setup to MySQL to pull data from a database. The data comes from gamemaker, which I think may be part of the problem. If I run the query itself with the name im looking for typed in:

so if I type the query like so (by typing the name I want to pull into the query) it'll pull the data, result 1:

```
pool.query('SELECT * FROM rp_accounts WHERE username=' +mysql.escape('john'),   function(err, rows){
        if(err) {
        throw err;
        }else{
    // Do something with result.

console.log("Result: "+rows.length);


}
})
```

But If I try to pass a variable to it

```
var playerName = value;

console.log("test:"+playerName+":test");

pool.query('SELECT * FROM rp_accounts WHERE username=' +mysql.escape('playerName'),
function(err, rows){
        if(err) {
        throw err;
        }else{
    // Do something with result.

console.log("Result: "+rows.length);


}
})
```

It has result 0, I know it takes time to pull data from the DB, but the query works totally fine, connects, finds and pulls a row if I "hard type" the name im looking for in.
if I pass a variable from gamemaker (which is done via buffer) I can see through a console.log that the name itself im pulling should be exactly what it needs to find (in this case "john"), it returns 0.

I've tried LIKE statements instead of =, multiple formatting (trim(), adding on brackets with concat(), etc) multiple brackets (i.e: [playerName]), =? with variables, quotations, removed the mySQL injection protection running it raw, and also tried pulling one specific table from that row, to see if its too much data to grab via a query or something? but no, still 0 result

Is it some kind of formatting after its received that its not actually reading the word as a word? (if that makes sense) Am I looking for rows when it should be fields?  As I can see it's extracting the correct username to pull (john) and it just seems like this should be working no issue and it's driving me up the wall and back again.

any help is appreciated, still learning,  as i've mentioned i've tried most of the obvious solutions, but I could of easily overlooked one. cheers.

Comment: Try after removing single quotes from `playerName` while using it in query.

Answer (score 0):

[Going off of this documentation.](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool#pool.query)

It could be that you have quotes around `playerName` in `+mysql.escape('playerName')`

First, try removing the quotes like this: `+mysql.escape(playerName)`

If that doesn't work, then try using this:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool()

string playerName = value.toString();

pool.query('SELECT * FROM rp_accounts WHERE username = $1', [playerName], (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('Error executing query', err.stack)
  }
  console.log(result.rows.length)
})
```

or this simplified version:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool()

string playerName = value.toString();

pool
  .query('SELECT $1', ['brianc'])
  .then(res => console.log(res.rows.length))
  .catch(err => console.error('Error executing query', err.stack))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply man, i'd be ripping my hair out still if i had any left.

I tried your suggestions but it still didn't come up with a result.

For anyone in the future: Turns out I was sending a "buffer_string" from game maker and I changed it to "buffer_text" and it now works properly! I'd assume it was some kind of whitespace issue between the two clients.

Thanks again for the reply, kept me guessing and I got it within 20 minutes :)